# Couple of links not working inside a sticky Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, href

This is the website, [http://girleducationproject.com/tempfile.html[1]](http://girleducationproject.com/tempfile.html%5b1%5d) The links in the navigation are all to anchors within the page except for the donate button and the donate link.
Clicking these two doesn't work but if right clicked they give the option to open link in new tab.
Please Advise. Thanks

Comment: Don't give us a link to the page, provide a minimal snippet that demonstrates the problem. Links break, making your question turn into nonsense; Examples will always be useful to others once your question has been answered. Plus, giving us a link assumes we'll chase down the needed information necessary to help you, but instead they tend to discourage people who would answer you, so help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have bound a click event to all navigation items via onePageNav plugin.

In your main.js add a filter in your navigation function:

```
// One Page Navigation
Navigation: function () {
    $('#menu').onePageNav({
        currentClass: 'current',
        scrollSpeed: 500,
        scrollOffset: 60,
        scrollThreshold: 0.2,
        easing: 'swing',
        filter: ':not(.external)' // <-- ADD THIS LINE
    });
},
```

Then, add a "external" class to your external links. Should solve it.

Another example is found in the docs (see *Filter Example*): https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav#filter-example

Comment: Sure, I am new here. I don't see how to do that. Got it. Done. Thanks